# Is there a way to put authentication on calendar subscription url which is in ics format in outlook?

Tags: node.js, authentication, url, outlook, icalendar

I have created a URL for subscribing to calendar events, mainly in Outlook. Since it has private information, I want users to be able to authenticate when subscribing to this calendar URL using a username and password. I don't want users to add passwords in the URL in order to authenticate.

Is there a way to achieve this where potentially a dialog box appears in outlook where user can enter their security credentials or some other way to authenticate? I'm using node.js on server side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a consistent way to do this: 
The RFC5545 specification is meant to "provide the definition of a common format for **openly** exchanging calendaring and scheduling information across the Internet".

Ie the receiving application must be able to access the url.  It may work for some if the application user is able to access the url at the time they are logged in, then fail at other times.  This is what annoyed me intensely with a school application.  One could login & download an ics file and import it BUT could not subscribe to it.  So whenever there were updates at a minimum each term, one had to login and re download & import.

Option:
You could have people login and get their unique obfuscated url.  This is how google calendar does it.  It is a 'private' but public url - anyone who gets sent that url can subscribe to it.   Since even if it weren't public,  the person who logs in, could also download it and send the file around, there is only 'some' additional minimal risk.

At any stage if people are no longer authorised to access the URL, then for their url you issue a 410, or issue empty ics file, or one with dummy events .

Answer (score 0):

Calendar subscription are just HTTP resources, so did you try to protect your resource with Basic Authentication, e.g. by using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth ?